# Selecting terms containing some expression

Tags: linear-algebra

Imagine I have an expression like

```
a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e
```

and I would like to obtain the term containing, for example, some power of a. In that case I would extract the two first terms. If I wanted to obtain the term b*e, I would extract the last.

How can I do it? I guess I should use `Cases` or something similar, but I don't understand its syntax.

Comment: Maybe `Most[CoefficientList[a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e, a]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
 Select[a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e, MemberQ[#, a | a^_] &]
```

=> a^2 b c + a k

```
Select[a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e, MemberQ[#, b] && FreeQ[#, a] &]
```

=> b e

```
Select[a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e, MemberQ[#, e] &]
```

=> b e

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want:

```
Cases[
 a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e,
 term_ /; ! FreeQ[term, a],
 {1}
]
```

> {a^2 b c, a k}

Note that the terms are not in the explicit order given as `Plus` is `Orderless`.  I am assuming this does not matter in practice but other measures can be taken of needed.

As a function:

```
selectTerms[expr_, pat_] := Cases[expr, term_ /; ! FreeQ[term, pat], {1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern matching. For instance to match `a` which is multiplied by something else you use

```
Cases[a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e, a*_]
```

or

```
Cases[a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e, a^_, 2]
```

The 2 is necessary because `a^2` appears deeper in you expression. Furthermore, to prevent trouble, you should be aware of `FullForm` which shows you the full underlying representation of your structure.

If something does not work, check the `FullForm` of you pattern and the thing you want to match first. You should start by

[Introduction to Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html)

### Update

The first part of my answer was not a ready to use solution. It assumed, that you do some work for yourself: Finding the patterns which help you to extract the parts you want.

Now, it seems you are asking something different: When you look at your expression as a **polynomial in a**, then it's worth looking at functions like `CoefficientList` (as already mentioned by Daniel in the comment), `Coefficient`, ... Please look here to have an overview

[Polynomial algebra](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/PolynomialAlgebra.html)

With this you get the expression containing **some** power (even the one with `a^0`) easily

```
CoefficientList[a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e, a]
```

Or you can pick one special power, like the second one

```
Coefficient[a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e, a, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, however the second one only returns a^2 instead of b*c ...
Maybe the best thing I could do is taking derivatives and evaluate at 0 ...

Comment: @pablo, please see my update. I maybe misinterpreted your question and hopefully gave now some more insight.

Answer (score 0):

One rather obvious way, useful for the situation you gave, is as follows: You can evaluate the expression at `e=0`:

```
(a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e)/.e->0
```

gives `a*k+a^2*b*c`, and

```
(a*k + (a^2)*b*c + b*e)/.a->0
```

gives `b*e`.

Comment: You probably mean `e -> 0` and `a -> 0` instead of `e=0` and `a=0`.

Comment: Although this solutions certainly works here, it may not in more general cases.  Note that I have made the correction recommended by @Karsten7.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. And yes, this does not work in more general cases.